# is there performance penalty to put object declaration inside a loop?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have the below snippet

```
for ( i = 1..100000 ) {
    String s = make_some_string(i); // this function depends on `i` only
    output_this_result(s);
}
```

Would that make any difference if the declaration of `String s` is moved outside the loop? I guess compiler is smart enough not to construct and destruct a string object in each loop. But what if it were a complicate customized `object`, instead of a `string`?

Comment: Test it. Look at the generated asm.

Comment: I think compiler is smart enough,but need test.

Comment: Apparantly a new string is produced and assigned by `make_some_string()` and later destroyed at each iteration anyways. Did you try to measure the difference of both attempts? What did you observe?

Comment: I think @JesperJuhl's comment is pretty much the case for all optimization attempts.

Comment: Please remember the 80/20 rule - do the measurements before trying to optimize. You may end up wasting a lot of time with little benefit before doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there performance penalty to put object declaration inside a loop?

There can be. It can depend on the type of the object and the optimizations preformed by the compiler. It also depends on what `make_some_string` returns (is the `String` constructed by copy, or conversion?) and possibly whether `make_some_string` is visible to the compiler (is it defined in same translation unit?).

If you declare the object inside, it will be constructed at the start of every iteration, and destroyed at the end. Calling a constructor and a destructor may be slower than not calling them. The calls can be optimized away only if they have no side-effects, and their implementation is visible to the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the third option, which is likely to be more efficient, when you only ask if the String should be declared in the loop or outside it.

Consider:

```
for ( i = 1..100000 ) {
    output_this_result(make_some_string(i)); // Depend on `i` only
}
```

By removing `s` entirely you don't have to decide where you would declare it. Clearly this requires that `output_this_result` does not take a string-reference and modify it, but given the name that seems logical.
And I doubt that any compiler generates worse code for this than the alternative.

(The for-loop syntax doesn't look like C++, but was part of the question.)